# CGColorGetComponents equivalent in Android

Tags: iphone, android, colors

I'm doing porting app from Iphone to Android related to RGB colors.

Is there any equivalent for `CGColorGetComponents` in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually get my argb values manually by using bit level operations.  You can wrap this in a helper method that returns it as an array if it's more convenient.

```
public int[] getColorComponents(int color)
{       
    int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xff;
    int red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
    int green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
    int blue = color & 0xff;
    return new int[] { alpha, red, green, blue };
}
```

If you need floats, you can do something like this

```
public float[] getColorComponents(int color)
{       
    int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xff;
    int red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
    int green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
    int blue = color & 0xff;
    float a = (float) alpha / 255;
    float r = (float) red / 255;
    float g = (float) green / 255;
    float b = (float) blue / 255;
    return new float[] { a, r, g, b };
}
```

If you're doing this many times (such as looping through the pixels in a Bitmap), you probably want to use a single array and pass it in, replacing the values in the method instead of instantiating a new array.

Comment: It's direct bit level operation. but still closest to the solution what I am looking for. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

In Android there's this way, without using (the sometime annoying Hex values) :

```
public static float[] CGColorGetComponents(CGColorRef color) {

    float[] components = new float[4];

    int currentRed = Color.red(color);
    components[0] = currentRed / 255f;

    int currentGreen = Color.green(color);
    components[1] = currentGreen / 255f;

    int currentBlue = Color.blue(color);
    components[2] = currentBlue / 255f;

    int currentAlpha = Color.alpha(color);
    components[3] = currentAlpha / 255f;

    return components;
}
```

For iOS to android equivalent elements I suggest you refer to http://docs.myappconverter.com/search.html?q=CGColor

***PS:*** The [MyAppConverter](https://www.myappconverter.com/) service is also free to use to convert an app from iOS to Android native code source, and at least you will have all components of your app ready to use in android.